# Remove or change "Details" in debian

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, root-filesystem

Debian 10, Gnome.
VMWare Workstation 16.1.1

In the settings menu. The details you can find for Debian. See screenshot.
Is there anyway to change these, remove the option or to remove certain categories of those details.

I'd much prefer removing the details option entirely too.[image]

Comment: Can you explain what your goal is and what you hope to accomplish?  Is it just that you don't want to see this option?  Are you trying to create a derivative distro and want to show those details?  Something else?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to see this option or rather. I don't want it to show that I am running a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option appears to be part of the GNOME settings configuration tool, and so the way to remove it would be to download the source package, make the change you want to remove this line, and then recompile it.

However, having said that, it's generally possible to determine that you're running in a virtual environment even though that UI won't list that.  There are tools like `virt-what` that can be easily used to determine this information, and in many cases, even unprivileged programs can easily detect this.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something that complicated. But, thank you.